# Spring Dependency injection scope confusion

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

I am new to Spring DI and i am implimenting DI for the first time in my webapplication.
it seems i am doing somehing wrong and it related the way i am using spring scope.here is my problem
i have a serive class where i am injecting various other object in order to achieve the desired functionality
here is my spring file entries

```
<bean id="ImportServiceImpl" class="ImportServiceImpl" factory-method="getInstance">
        <property name="browseDirectory" ref="browseDirectoryImpl"/>
        <property name="xmlUnmarshaller" ref="xmlUnmarshallerImpl"/>
        <property name="Adaptar" ref="AdaptarImpl"/>
        <property name="DAOService" ref="DAO"/>
     </bean>

     <bean id="browseDirectoryImpl" class="BrowseDirectoryImpl" factory-method="getInstance" />
     <bean id="xmlUnmarshallerImpl" class="XMLUnmarshallerImpl"/>
     <bean id="AdaptarImpl" class="AdaptarImpl" factory-method="getInstance"/>
```

now in my adaptarImpl class i have a refrence to some other object which is being initialized in the constructor

```
private AdaptarImpl(){
    foo=new Foo();
}
```

now for the first time when the server start and this service run fist time everything is fine foo is being initilized to its proper initialization value but for all other subsequent calls Spring is returing refrence to the previous initialized foo object where i want that for each new request a new instance of foo should be created.
it apperas to me that the factory method being used in the above code `factory-method="getInstance"`
is being called only once when server called and all other subsequent calles returning same refrence where i want a new instance for every request.
here is my facory method

```
public static ImportServiceImpl getInstance(){
    return new ImportServiceImpl();
}
```

i know i am doing basics wrong in DI but not sure where it is.I am using Struts2 for MVC and for service layer using Spring DI
any help in this regard will  be helpful

Thanks
Umesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but it sounds like you ought to ask Spring to inject the reference to Foo into your AdapterImpl and make its scope "request". If you need Spring to control object creation, don't call "new".

Comment: i was also thinking about making it request but was not sure about it as i am just beginner in spring so know much only about scope and siglton :)

Comment: ill give you the +1 -- I tend to point to documentation and tell exactly where the answer is, you just got right to the point ;)

Comment: hvgotcodes:since i am using ImportServiceImpl as entry point so i guess i also need to make its scope as request since along with adaptar class,please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Thanks Duffymo and hvgotcodes its working now as per expected flow

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look at

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes

and look at table 3.3.

Comment: Why the ancient version? Spring 2.0 is more than 5 years old!!! Here's the current version of the [Bean Scopes Table](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes)